# How to refer to the workbook where a function is used in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a user-defined function called `SheetAtIndex` that returns the name of the sheet at the specified index in a workbook.

At first I used `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Index).Name` to get the name of the sheet. Anytime I switch to another open workbook the results became messed up. *No surprise there.*

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index).Name` worked for some time till I realized I have to duplicate the code in every workbook that needs the UDF. In addition every file that needs the function must be saved as a macro-enable workbook

**Final decision**: Put the function in my personal macro book.

**Problem**: How to reference the workbook/worksheet where the function will be called from?

Comment: Additionally to `Application.ThisCell` you may look at `Application.Caller` also. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A UDF can get a reference to the cell that called it with [`Application.ThisCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thiscell)

Once you have a reference to the calling cell, you can get the worksheet (`.WorkSheet`) and workbook (`.WorkSheet.Parent`) from there

```
Function SheetAtIndex(Index As Variant) As String
    SheetAtIndex = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets(Index).Name
End Function
```

Or, to get a reference to the Worksheet

```
Function SheetAtIndex(Index As Variant) As Worksheet
    Set SheetAtIndex = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets(Index)
End Function
```

Comment: Why is Index parameter specified as Variant?

Comment: _Why is Index parameter specified as Variant?_: Habit.  If this is _all_ you are doing with this UDF then typing  it as `Long` would be just fine.  I tend to use `Variant` parameters for UDF's so I can access a passed range object (_if_ a range is passed).